# Minimum $n$ such that a random sequence of $n$ numbers have a number congruent to $-2\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the expected minimum $n$ such that a random sequence of $n$ numbers have a number congruent to $-2\pmod p$, where $p$ is a prime?

Does this have anything to with the distribution of $n$ numbers or with the prime? I am stuck at ths problem. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If the sequence is random, the residue mod p is random as well, so in average we will need $p$ entries to get such a number.

Comment: As stated, the problem doesn't really make sense. When you say "expected minumum", expectation with respect to what distribution??

Comment: I am guessing that you mean "suppose we draw uniformly from the numbers $0, \cdots, p-1$, with replacement.  What is the expected number of times it takes to draw $p-2$"?   If so, this is just a standard geometric distribution for trials with success probability $\frac 1p$,  so the answer is $p$.

Comment: @lulu yes, that is close to what I expect, so you could post an answer

Comment: But if my interpretation is correct, this is just the standard [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), so there is really nothing more to be done.